# Is it possible to sketch a normal distribution of a difference?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have struck a problem with an assignment and would much appreciate some guidance.

The question asks to sketch a distribution of a difference between two random variables with a normal distribution.

Expected value of X – Y = E(X-Y) 
= 110 – 105 = 5mm

Var(X) = 100

Var(Y) = 25

SD(X+Y) = square root of 125
= 11.180

Am I right in thinking that I can simply sketch such a normal distribution using 5 as the mean and 11.18 as the standard deviation? i.e. with values of the distribution being between -3sd and +3sd from the mean.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: You have not made your thought process in getting the parameters $E(X-Y)$ or $SD(X-Y)$ at all clear.  Perhaps your assignment was "to sketch" such a distribution, but you should try to connect this conclusion with material you been taught, for which the assignment presumably serves as a reinforcement.

Comment: Yes. You have found the correct mean and SD of $X-Y$. Your plan (as far as described) for making the sketch seems sound. I agree with @hardmath that you should show some intermediate steps in the process and explain what you are doing.